# Multi-step registration form with middleware and auth causing an infinite loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to write a multi-step registration form where the first form registers the user and the following forms complete user details (separate pages). My goal is to allow the user (by error or on purpose) to exit after registering the first form allowing them to login later and set them where they left off.

I added a database table "register_steps" to determine which page the user has completed then I am trying to pull this data into a middleware and redirect appropriately.

It looks like I am getting an infinite loop conflict between Auth's redirectTo and my Register's redirect middleware.

### Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CompleteRegistration
{
    /**
     * Redirect user if profile is not complete
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()){
            $step = Auth::user()->registration_steps;
            switch ($step) {
                case 1:
                    return redirect('/register/profile');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return redirect('/register/photo');
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### Routes

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationBasic')->name('register.basic');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@registerBasic');
Route::get('register/profile', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationProfile');
Route::post('register/profile', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationProfile');
Route::get('register/photo', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationPhoto');
Route::post('register/photo', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationPhoto');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

// Website Pages
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/browse', 'ProfileController@show')->middleware('auth', 'register');
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->middleware('auth', 'register');
Route::get('/profile/edit', 'ProfileController@edit')->middleware('auth', 'register');
```

### Kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'register' => \App\Http\Middleware\CompleteRegistration::class
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up separating out the extra forms into a another controller rather than the RegisterController so it wouldn't redirect and then used the middleware in my OP to check the db to see if the forms have been completed, if not, redirect to the uncompleted form.